# event and trigger doesn't work for model and views

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have the following model:

```
    App.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot : '/item',
            // Default attributes
            defaults: {
                user_has_liked: false,
            },
            initialize: function(){
                this.on('item-id-changed', this.onItemIdChange);
            },
          onItemIdChange: function(itemId){
            console.log('item id change');
            this.set({'id': itemId});
            var that = this;
            this.fetch({
                success: function (item) {

                }
            })  
        },
```

and the following trigger on click:

on my other view, which is not the view that this model is binded to I have:

```
loadNewItem: function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var self =  $(ev.currentTarget);
        var itemId = $(self).attr('data-item-id');
        //trigger a new event for listener
        if (itemId) {
            console.log('triggger');
            this.trigger('item-id-changed', itemId);
        }
    },
```

why is it that `onItemIdChange` is never called?

Comment: The `this` in `this.trigger('item-id-changed', itemId)` is the view and `this` in `this.on('item-id-changed', this.onItemIdChange)` is the model, correct?

Comment: that is correct @muistooshort

Comment: But you have to listen to events from the thing that is triggering them so of course it doesn't work. Perhaps you want a global event bus instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
this.on('item-id-changed', this.onItemIdChange);
```

to this:

```
this.on('change:item-id-changed', this.onItemIdChange, this);
```

Comment: I have added anothe rparameter, try now @adit

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing this in a view,

use `this.model.trigger('item-id-changed', itemId);`

here `this` will refer to the view so you need to refer the model (triggering a model is the right way to do).

Comment: but the model I want to trigger is not the model that is associated with this view.. it's another one

Comment: Suppose you have declared in view's initialize as `var myModel = new app.SomeModel();` so write `this.someModel = myModel;`

and then in your function trigger as `this.someModel.trigger(...)`

Comment: writing `this.somModel` will make the "someModel" available to the whole view.

Answer (score 0):

So the `this` in

```
this.trigger('item-id-changed', itemId)
```

is the view and `this` in

```
this.on('item-id-changed', this.onItemIdChange)
```

is the model. If some Backbone object, `o`, is triggering events, then you have to `o.on(...)` to be notified about those events. You're triggering events on a view but listening for those events on a model so nothing useful happens.

I get the impression that you really want a global event bus:

```
app.events = _({}).extend(Backbone.Events);
```

where `app` is your application's global namespace. Then you'd say:

```
app.events.trigger('item-id-changed', itemId);
```

in your view and your model would:

```
app.events.on('item-id-changed', this.onItemIdChange, this);
```

Note the third `context` argument to [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on), that ensures that `this` inside `onItemIdChange` is what you expect it to be (i.e. the model). Alternatively, you could use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) or [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) in the model's constructor to bind the method to the instance, then you wouldn't need the third argument to `on`.

Don't forget to call [`off`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off) when your model goes away.

Here's a simplified demo of the technique: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dc523/